# Local Notifications - Repeat Interval / custom time doesn't work

Tags: cocoa-touch, notifications, uilocalnotification

Can't seem to get some basic notifications to work.

I'm using local notifications to bring alarms sounds to the user.

I can get a notification hourly to work.

I can't seem to get one to work every half hour (every 30 minutes, or at 30 minutes or 1 hour) or every 15 minutes.

How do I put an offset to the hourly repeat interval? The notifications are not firing.

If this is not possible, how would I manually write a loop that did it 'till the limit of 64 queued notifications?

```
UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];

NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSInteger hour = [components hour];

NSDate *h = [calendar dateBySettingHour:hour+1 minute:0 second:0 ofDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
     NSDate *f = [calendar dateBySettingHour:hour minute:15 second:0 ofDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
     NSDate *ha = [calendar dateBySettingHour:hour minute:30 second:0 ofDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
     NSDate *q = [calendar dateBySettingHour:hour minute:45 second:0 ofDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
    if (selected == 0)
        {
                UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
                if (notification)
                {
                    notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitHour;
                    notification.alertBody = nil;
                    notification.alertAction = nil;
                    notification.soundName = @"4.mp3";
                    notification.fireDate = h;
                    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
                }
        }
        else if (selected == 1)
        {
            UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
            if (notification)
            {
                notification.fireDate = ha;
                notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitHour;
                notification.alertBody = nil;
                notification.alertAction = nil;
                notification.soundName = @"2.mp3";
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
                notification.soundName = @"4.mp3";
                notification.fireDate = h;
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
            if (notification)
            {
                notification.fireDate = f;
                notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitHour;
                notification.alertBody = nil;
                notification.alertAction = nil;

                notification.soundName = @"1.mp3";
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];

                notification.soundName = @"2.mp3";
                notification.fireDate = ha;
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];

                notification.soundName = @"3.mp3";
                notification.fireDate = q;
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];

                notification.soundName = @"4.mp3";
                notification.fireDate = h;
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I tried it again, but it was actually working, but the asset was not imported properly. I just deleted the sound file in finder and reimported them and the app was firing the notifs right!